# Setting frame not working for UIImage in UITableView with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, autolayout

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` as below picture:
[image: /Users/novinfard/Desktop/stack_new.png]

The images have different height and width, I need to keep their aspect ratio and show them in my tableview. So I configured the Controller as below code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    ...

    UINib *nibResponderImage = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ResponderImageCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nibResponderImage forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ResponderImage"];

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0;

    ...
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ...

    MessageLTableViewCell *cell = (MessageLTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ResponderImage" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.mediaThumb setFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];
    [cell.mediaThumb layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    cell.mediaThumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_image"];

    [cell.mediaThumb setFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];
    [cell.mediaThumb layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    ...
}
```

The sample image's size is large. In addition, I set constant frame size to debug it easier.

The problem is that the new frame not set. So the result will be the below picture:
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: try calling the  [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints] after u resize the imageview

Comment: @Mr.T Not works unfortunately.

Comment: did yiu gave any height constraint ?

Comment: @Mr.T as you see in the first picture, No.

Comment: Also, when I cropped the image before setting the image, it works as well. I think there is a problem with AutoLayout.

Comment: You can't set frames directly if you are using autolayout, you have to edit the constraints to resize/reposition the views

Comment: as @dan said, you have to add a constraint programatically or in nib for the height/width, otherwise you will end up with view's `intrinsicContentSize`, i.e. image size here

Comment: +1 @dan with adding just height constraint to the `UIImage` and changing it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the problem solved, however it caused breaking constraints. You can see what I configure for cell constraints in the first picture, in addition with new Height constraint to the `UIImage`.